# Different database connections per thread, same model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, activerecord

I would like to be able to connect to different databases in separate threads, and query the same model in each database. For instance, without threads, I can do something like:

```
# given 'db1' and 'db2' are rails environments with connection configurations
['db1', 'db2'].each do |db|
  Post.establish_connection(db)

  Post.where(title: "Foo") 
end
Post.establish_connection(Rails.env)
```

This will loop over the two databases and look up the posts in each. I need to be able to do this in parallel using threads, like:

```
['db1', 'db2'].each do |db|
  threads = Thread.new do
    Post.establish_connection(db)

    Post.where(title: "Foo")
  end 
end
threads.join
Post.establish_connection(Rails.env)
```

But quite clearly, establishing a new connection pool in each thread using the global Post class isn't threadsafe.

What I'd like to do is establish a new connection pool in each thread. I got this far:

```
['db1', 'db2'].each do |db|
  threads = Thread.new do
    conf = ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionSpecification.new(Rails.configuration.database_configuration[db], "mysql2_connection")
    pool = ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionPool.new(conf)
    pool.with_connection do |con|
      # problem is, I have this con object but using the Post class still uses the thread's default connection.
      Post.where(title: "Foo")
    end
  end 
end
threads.join
```

There has to be a way for me to change the connection pool that ActiveRecord uses, on a thread by thread basis?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?  I'm kind of in the same boat now.

Comment: I wasn't able to get it to work with AR, I had to use the connection directly, I explain here: http://www.wordofmike.net/j/shard-query-rails-querying-multiple-databases